# Find prime numbers $a, b, c$ such that $a^b+c$ is a prime

Tags: number-theory

Please help me find all $a, b, c \in \mathbb{P}$ such that $a^b+c$ is a prime

Example I just can find: $2^3 + 5 = 13 \in \mathbb{P}$

Comment: there is probably (I'll be as cautious too :-)) an infinity of solutions : consider just $a=b=2$ you'll get $c\in{3,7,13,19,37,43,67,79,\cdots}$. Are there more hypothesis than indicated?

Comment: short table for $a>2$ of first [a,b,c] solutions : [3, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 2]
[3, 139, 2]
[5, 3, 2]
[5, 17, 2]
[11, 5, 2]
[23, 11, 2]
[29, 3, 2]
[41, 23, 2]
[47, 113, 2]
[53, 7, 2]
[71, 3, 2]
[71, 13, 2]
[71, 31, 2]
[83, 3, 2]
[113, 3, 2]
[131, 23, 2]
[149, 5, 2]
[149, 13, 2]
[149, 17, 2]
[173, 3, 2]
[179, 5, 2]
[191, 29, 2]
[197, 5, 2]
[197, 41, 2]

Comment: Thank you to all, teacher's challenge is so ... :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are almost certainly infinitely many: classifying them is probably very difficult.

For example, take $a=b=2$. It has long been conjectured that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4+c$, where $c$ is prime. Tis problem is related to the famous **twin primes** problem. There is a great deal of numerical evidence suggesting that there are infinitely many primes $c$ such that $4+c$ is prime. But (so far) there is no proof. Examples are easy: $4+3$, $4+7$, $4+13$, and so on.

It is in fact conjectured that for *any* even number $e$, there are infinitely many primes of the form $e+c$, where $c$ is prime. That would mean that in particular there are infinitely many primes of the form $2^b+c$, where $c$ is any prime. Again, there are many examples: $2^3+3$, $2^3+5$, $2^3+11$, $2^5+5$, and so on.

For odd $a$, the problem is different, for then the only possibility is $c=2$. But it is not known whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $a^b+2$, where $a$ is an odd prime and $b$ is prime. Examples are not hard to find, such as $3^2+2$, $3^3+2$, $5^3+2$, $3^{29}+2$.

Comment: $11^2+2$ isn't prime...  Did you perhaps mean $11^3+2$?  Except that appears to be divisible by $31$...

Comment: @abiessu: Thank you for spotting the error. I don't recall what I was thinking of (if anything!) when I typed $11^2+2$. Have replaced it by a larger unrelated example.